# Do Zircon gems help with fishing for rare items?

Tags: fate

While playing [Fate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate_%28video_game%29), I am wondering if using Zircon gems (Increases chance of finding magical items) effect fishing in any way. I have two weapons with 3 Superior Zircon gems each, and I don't see a noticeable difference in finding rare items.

Does the item it's on affect it at all? For example, since you use a fishing pole to fish and your weapons disappear on the character.

Answer (score 1):

Not likely. I tested this between two different gear sets. One with 2% magic item discovery, the other with 102% and I found my results to be nearly identical. I did a trial of thirty with each. With the 2% trial, I caught 20 fish, 7 gems/jewelry, and 3 artifacts. For the 102% trial I caught 21 fish, 7 gems/jewelry, and 2 artifacts. In the 102% build, 57% alone was in armor.